# Enforce File/document locking in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: lock

I currently received a request in which the document/folder should be locked after (x)days (after the created date). Is it possible to enforce document/folder locking?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable **In Place Record Management** Feature on your Site Collection, and configure the record declaration settings in such a way that those document which are declared as records are not allowed to be either edited or deleted (locked to be precise.) as shown below:

Go To **Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Record Declaration Settings**

Set your Record Restriction as shown in the image below:
[image: Record Restrictions]

You can then restrict users from revoking the record declaration by setting the declaration roles as shown below: 
[image: Record roles]

Next, set up Information Management Policy Settings on your document library for the Content Types **Document** and **Folder**

Add a new retention stage and configure it as shown in the image below:

[image: Retention Stage]

You should be able to achieve your requirement this way in a completely out of the box manner. Alternatively you write a Timer Job in order to achieve the same thing programmatically.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Declaring-bbeae3c3

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly remove all the edit permissions from the document. Meaning people could then still read, but not modify. Of course you could remove all read permissions too, but I imagine your administrator would need visibility of this.